# What is the best method of concatenating a series of binary files into one file?

Tags: c#

I have a series of PDF byte arrays in a arraylist files that i wish to concatenate into one file,

Currently when the PDF application tries to open the file is it corrupted:

```
foreach (byte[] array in files)
{
    using (Stream s = new MemoryStream(downloadbytes))
    {
        s.Write(array, 0, array.Length);
    }
}
```

downloadbytes is the resultant concatenated array of bytes below is another implementation which also failed

```
foreach (byte[] array in files)
{
    System.Buffer.BlockCopy(array, 0, downloadbytes, offset, array.Length);
    offset += array.Length;
}
```

any pointers?

Comment: Are you actually trying to glue PDFs together by concatenating the files, or do you have several chunks that make up one file when glued together?

Comment: If it's the latter of @Samir 's comment, then use `cat file1 file2 file3 > file.pdf`

Comment: It's the wrong subject. It should be "How to concatenate PDF Files"

Answer (score 2):

If you've got byte arrays, you can just write them directly:

```
using (Stream output = File.OpenWrite("output.pdf"))
{
    foreach (byte[] array in files)
    {
        output.Write(array, 0, array.Length);
    }
}
```

That will effectively concatenate the byte arrays... but if each byte array represents an individual, complete PDF file you shouldn't expect the result of the concatenation to be a single valid PDF file. Combining PDFs isn't just a case of writing one after the other. You'll need to use a PDF library (e.g. iText) to do that.

To put it another way: what do you get if you build 5 two-bedroom houses next to each other? Not a ten-bedroom mansion...

Comment: @Andrew: I wouldn't expect it to, if you really do just have a series of complete PDFs - for exactly the reasons I stated. You'll need to use something like iText.

Answer (score 2):

You will likely need to use a PDF library to concatenate the files.  Take a look at [iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/).

Answer (score 1):

```
using (var result = File.OpenWrite("result.bin"))
{
    foreach (byte[] array in files)
    {
        result.Write(array, 0, array.Length);
    }
}
```

Also you talk about PDFs. Don't expect that if you have a series of PDF files and concatenate the binaries you will receive a valid PDF file by just adding the bytes. If this is what you want you may take a look at [iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/) which allows you to [concatenate PDFs](http://khsw.blogspot.com/2006/04/merge-pdf-files-using-itextsharp.html).

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use a PDF handling tool to do this job as PDF files cannot be simply concatenated to form a single PDF. PDF files follow a specification, you can't just join them together. Think about XML, you cannot just join XML files together to form a single XML file.

Answer (score 1):

You can't just merge the bytes together - you need a 3rd party library, for instance PDFSharp.  PDFSharp has a tutorial on merging documents:

http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/CombineDocuments-sample.ashx